# Youtube iframe fullscreen

Tags: iframe, youtube, fullscreen

hope everyone is ok.
I need to build a page in our company's website where we're putting some videos of our production.
The problem is, i can't seem to find a way to make the videos available in fullscreen mode for the visitors.
I've done pratically every solution  that i've found, but none seems to work. I've done:

```
<iframe allow="fullscreen;">
---
<iframe src="your_page_url" 
    allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"
    mozallowfullscreen="mozallowfullscreen" 
    msallowfullscreen="msallowfullscreen" 
    oallowfullscreen="oallowfullscreen" 
    webkitallowfullscreen="webkitallowfullscreen">
</iframe> 
---
allowFullScreen="allowFullScreen" and frameBorder="0"
---
<iframe 
    id="player" 
    src="URL here" 
    allowfullscreen="true">
</iframe>
---
```

But none of that worked.. Any help here is welcome!

Answer (score 0):

its very easy if you wants to add youtube videos in iframe .you just have to add iframe in src embed word like that

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/watch?v=fbS2O4VETAo&t=2s" name="myFrame"></iframe>
```

after youtube.com/embed/Example url

Comment: That's not at all what i'm trying to do, i'm trying to enable fullscreen mode in an Youtube video ON an iframe.